# UITableView wrong section titles

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been stuck on this error for quite some time now. I have a `UITabBar` with 2 tabs. The first one contains a `UITableViewController` with meals on different dates of the week. The second tab contains a `UIViewController` with a login screen.

The `UITableViewController` is called 'EettafelView'. It gets it's meals (using Alamofire) from an online source and presents them in the application. They are cached in `CoreData` and retrieved using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to present them. For this i'm using the default `UITableViewDelegates` (numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections etc) - If they are relevant i'll post them in an edit.

When the tableview loads and i have set the fetchController and have performed a fetch i pretty-print its objects to test what it holds and if the sort-descriptors have done their job. This leads to the following:

```
Hollandse stoof met bokbier - Optional("maandag, 20 feb.")
    Gehaktballetjes
    Quorn gehakt
Stamppot van verse spinazie - Optional("dinsdag, 21 feb.")
    Rookworst
    Kaasspies
Indiase Curry - Optional("woensdag, 22 feb.")
    Kip
    Bloemkool
Pasta Mexicane - Optional("donderdag, 23 feb.")
    Gehakt
    Tofu en Bruine Bonen
Boeuf des Gardiens - Optional("vrijdag, 24 feb.")
    Rundvlees
    Kastanjechampignons
```

With pretty-print code:

```
if let objects = fetchController?.fetchedObjects as? [Gerecht] {
    for object in objects {
        print("\(object.basis ?? "") - \(object.dateString)")
        print("\t\(object.vlees ?? "")")
        print("\t\(object.vega ?? "")")
    }
}
```

This is exactly how it is supposed to be. Thus the FetchController holds the right objects and has them sorted correctly. The view however looks likes this:

[image: EettafelView]

The section titles are wrong. The code to retrieve the section titles is as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if let sections = fetchController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
        return sections[section].name
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Which is I think as generic as it can be. What can be the problem of it retrieving the wrong section titles?

EDIT: - CellForRow Method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Eettafel") as? Eettafel_Cell
    let gerecht = fetchController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Gerecht
    if let gerecht = gerecht {
        cell?.gerecht = gerecht
    }

    return cell!
}
```

EDIT - Gerecht in cellForRow

printing the description of the NSManagedObject (breakpoint at if-let gerecht) gives:

```
Printing description of gerecht.some:
<Almanapp.Gerecht: 0x1740b77c0> (entity: Gerecht; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://A6B5411D-DF77-43DE-8084-86C76C42F68A/Gerecht/p3> ; data: {
    basis = "Hollandse stoof met bokbier";
    date = "2017-02-20 00:23:07 +0000";
    dateString = "maandag, 20 feb.";
    status = nil;
    vega = "Quorn gehakt";
    vlees = Gehaktballetjes;
})
```

Which is correct.

Comment: Hollandse Stoof met bokbier should be on a monday (maandag) (as per console output) but in the screenshot is on a tuesday (dinsdag)

Comment: Please, change your titleForHeaderInSection for:
return fetchController?.sections[section].name
And tell me what do you get now

Comment: what are you using for your `sectionNameKeyPath` in your fetchedResultsController?

Comment: @JuanCurti Didn't make a difference. Still the same as in the screenshot.

Comment: @JonRose I use the sectionNameKeyPath: "dateString"

Comment: @Emptyless Edit your answer and add the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, please

Comment: @JuanCurti added.

Comment: The strangest thing is that when the 'UITableView' reloads is that the titles are placed correctly. But a restart of the app again reverts to the old incorrect behaviour

Comment: I think the problem is in your object. Try debugging your app with a breakpoint on if let gerecht = gerecht {, and see what gerecht has (Check if that is correct). Also see the differences between your cellForRowAtIndexPath and the function you use to reload the tableView. Add it to the post if you want to, and I will help you

Comment: @JuanCurti I have added the 'print description' of 'gerecht' but it holds the right data. The rows are sorted correctly but it is just displaying a random section title like those are not sorted or something.

Comment: @Emptyless Ok. I will add the possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your titleForHeaderInSection function for this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     if let gerecht = fetchController?.object(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)) as? Gerecht {
         return gerecht.dateString 
     }else{ 
         return nil 
     }
}
```

I think the problem is you were using:

```
if let sections = fetchController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
        return sections[section].name
```

Check that and tell me please

Comment: Changed to: if let gerecht = fetchController?.object(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)) as? Gerecht {
            return gerecht.dateString
        } else {
            return nil
        }

Else it wouldn't compile, but that works

Comment: Yes it works, ill mark it as an answer. But it is still strange how the fetchController sections aren't ordered then. Since it holds the right objects in the right order but somehow the sections aren't ordered the same.

Comment: @Emptyless That's true, I would check how the data is fetched and parsed into a Gerecht object to see if there's any mistake there.

Comment: That's **wrong solution**: secitons contains wrong cells!

Answer (score 5):

You need to **add sort descriptor by sectionNameKeyPath** for your **fetchRequest** as **FIRST** item in array of sort descriptors:

```
  let request: NSFetchRequest<YourMO> = YourMO.fetchRequest()
    let dateSorting = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    let sectionSorting = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionIdentifier", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sectionSorting, dateSorting]
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)
```